maximal groups of elements always occurring together
I'm looking for the terminology used to describe the following concept.
Given a set $S$ and a family of subsets of $S$, let $P$ be the maximal partition of $S$ (maximal in the size of the elements of $P$, minimal in the size of $P$) such that every element of the family is the union of some elements in $P$.
So the partitions in $P$ collect the elements that always occur together in the sets of the family.
How is $P$ or the process of determining $P$ usually called?
It seems to be the same question as Finding distinct subsets of sets, except that I'm not looking for an algorithm (as it seems to be pretty clear).

Well, if the family of subsets of $S$ were spontaneously declared to be the open sets of $S$ (and satisfied the requirements of being a topology on $S$), your $P$ would be a minimal base (or minimal basis, depending on the linguistic background of who is writing) for that topology.

@EricTowers Thanks for the pointer. When researching my question before, I also came across topologies, but I think that I would have to assume more strucuture on $S$ and the family. In my context, the elements of $S$ usually don't have any particular relationship, like an order. But in analogy, I could call $P$ a base as well, would make sense.

Maybe the the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family is what you're after. $P$ is the unique partition that generates the same $\sigma$-algebra as the family.

^ Actually, my last statement isn't quite right. If $S$ is uncountable and $F=\mathcal P(S)$, then $\sigma(F)=F$ whereas $P$ consists of all the singletons, so $\sigma(P)$ consists of just the countable and co-countable subsets of $S$.
